# Will the Intel W2600CR2 accept Xeon E5-2600 v1 CPUs?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, compatibility, xeon

Given the currently very low price of used 8 core Xeon E5-2670 v1 CPUs, I'm looking for a matching dual LGA2011 motherboard.

The [Intel W2600CR2](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/server-motherboards/server-board-w2600cr.html) fits the bill but is specified by Intel to support Intel Xeon E5-26xx v2 CPUs (note the v2 part). I am hoping the specification is like this simply because the Xeon E5-26xx v1 is past its end-of-life date.

Can I plug two Xeon E5-2670 v1 into an Intel W2600CR2 motherboard and expect them to work?

Comment: It should indeed work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a [list](http://ark.intel.com/products/56338/#@compatibility) including first-generation Xeon E5-26xx CPU for the motherboard in question.

The W2600CR2 motherboard is compatible with all Xeon E5-26xx v1 CPUs.

Only the third generation (Xeon E5-26xx v3) will not mix with previous ones due to the different pin connections and socket (LGA2011-3).